# minorTicks not Visible

Tags: kendo-ui

I am not able to make minorTicks visible on yAxis. It works fine on xAxis.

http://jsbin.com/alupin/16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `minorTicks` is not correctly defined. You wrote:

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        format: "{0:N0}"
    },
    line: {
        width: 1
    }
},
tooltip: {
    visible: true,
    format: "{3}: {2:N0} applications",
    opacity: 1
},
minorTicks: { visible: true }
```

when it should be:

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        format: "{0:N0}"
    },
    line: {
        width: 1
    },
    minorTicks: { visible: true }
},
tooltip: {
    visible: true,
    format: "{3}: {2:N0} applications",
    opacity: 1
}
```

I moved `minorTicks: { visible: true }` inside `yAxis` definition

Comment: Oops sorry. Blunder. It will help to have minorTicks in the documentation as it is missing for the xAxis and yAxis.